# C++: finding a specific digit in a number

Tags: c++, math, digits

Someone please guide me how to check whether a specific digit exists in an `integer` or not. **for the sake of code optimization I am trying to avoid the use of `strings` or any kind of `loops`** to iterate over all the `digits` of the `integer`.

If I need to find out whether `4` exists the in an integer or not, input and the output samples are given below:

**Sample Input:**

```
154
```

**Sample Output:**

```
true
```

**Desired Code:**

```
bool ifExists(int digit, int number)
{
    if()
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Possible Logic:**

I believe there must be a *mathematical approach* which will do the job in the `if` condition, however I am unable to find such method in `cmath` library.

Comment: There is no way I know of that doesn't involve going over the sequence of digits in a number.

Comment: What leads you to believe there is an approach?

Comment: I saw this problem on a coding website and the requirement was to find the number of `2's` in a digit with the best optimal code

Comment: Is "number of 2's in a number" a question for digits or for the highest power of 2 that is a factor of that number?

Comment: the problem was about to iterate all the digits between two random integers `num1` and `num2`, and then finding all the number of `2's` occurred in the integers which are between `num1` and `num2`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact formulation of the problem you are *actually* trying to solve. Also it's best to include a sample input and output.

Comment: I have _formatted_ the sample input and output as it was already included.

Comment: While I'm pretty sure that @StoryTeller is right about the need to decompose one integer into its digits to find out if there is a specific digit within, this needs does not persist for _each_ number when dealing with a range of numbers! Once the bigger value has been decomposed the digits of the other values in the range can be computed based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert integer to string, do a string search for digit.

---

The "mathematical" method would have to do the same, compute the digit sequence by division/remainder by 10 and compare with the given digit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response :) please see the updated problem.

Comment: Well, then you are probably out of luck, there is no simple way to get all of the digits of the decimal representation from the binary representation. -- Searching in the digit sequence requires a loop, so loop prohibition is too high an obstacle.

Comment: so `loop` can be the only solution ?

Comment: @ItbanSaeed yes, you cannot do it without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

A mathematical approach would be possible i think. By using log(x) in some crazy way.

But ones for surey you should use string or a loop by dividing by 10. log(x) requires far more resources than the way you want to use.

Also string or dividing by 10 is far more easy to read than a mathimatical solution.

For the mathimatical solution.

I suggest you try to transform the decimal number in a binary representation of it. Then it could be possible to create a filter for the digit you look for. By joining the filter and the transformed value through a bitwise & you could get what you seek. Im not sure if that realy is possible but that would be my first idea for an approach.

But as i said before. This method will be very expensive to the cpu and will be hard to read.